# Слишком Очень Много

Tags: перевод

This is one of my many attempts to get some vocabulary into my head. I was thinking if you guys have any good, interesting or funny Russian words/phrases that can replace some of the Оченьs below. For example, are there better Russian expressions for Очень много, Очень громко,... etc? I'm hoping to hear some amusing expressions; even slang!

Very afraid — terrified Очень боюсь — страшно

Very angry — furious. Очень зол — в ярости; как собака — Она злая, как собака.

Very bad — atrocious Очень плохо — отвратительная

Very beautiful — exquisite Очень красивый — очаровательный

Very big — immense Очень большой — огромный

Very bright — dazzling Очень яркий — ослепляющий

Very capable — accomplished. Очень способный — схватывает на лету (about learning)

Very clean — spotless Очень чистые —

Very clever — brilliant Очень умный — гениальный

Very close — Очень близко — Под носом

Very cold — freezing. Очень холодно - морозно (adverb), дубак, холодрыга (slang)

Very dangerous — Очень опасна —

Very dirty — squalid Очень грязный — грязный как свинья

Very dry — parched Очень сухой — выжженная

Very expensive — exorbitant. Очень дорогой — непомерный

Very far — Очень далеко — За горизонтом

Very fast — quick Очень быстро — Как пуля

Very fat — Очень толстый — Жиртрест

Very few — Очень мало —

Very fierce — ferocious Очень жестокой — свирепый

Very good — superb Очень хорошо — превосходный

Very happy — jubilant Очень рад — ликующая

Very hot — Очень жарко —

Very hungry — ravenous Очень голоден — голодный как волк

Very large — colossal Очень большой — колоссальная

Very late — Очень поздно —

Very lazy — Очень ленив —

Very little — Очень мало —

Very lively — vivacious Очень живой —

Very long — Очень долго —

Very loud — Очень громко — ;как потерпевший — Что вы кричите как потерпевший?

Very loved — adored Очень любил — обожаемая

Very much — Очень много —

Very neat — immaculate. Очень ?

Very noisy — Очень шумно —

Very often — Очень часто — Как из пулемета

Very old — ancient Очень старый — древний

Very poor — destitute Очень плохое — Нищий

Very pretty — beautiful Очень красивая —

Very quiet — silent Очень тихий —

Very risky — perilous Очень рискованно — опасно

Very roomy — spacious; Очень просторный —

Very serious — solemn Очень серьезно — торжественное

Very short — Очень короткий — огрызок

Very skinny — Очень худой —

Very slow — Очень медленно — Как черепаха

Very small — tiny Очень мало — крошечный

Very soft — Очень мягкий —

Very strong — unyielding; Очень сильный — Непобедимый

Very stupid — idiotic. Очень глу́пый — идиотизм; тупой, тупой как пробка

Very tall — Очень высок —

Very tasty — delicious Очень вкусно —

Very thin — gaunt; Очень тонкий — тонюсенький.

Very thin — skinny; Очень худой — Тощий.

Very tired — exhausted. Очень устал - вымотанный (participle)

Very valuable — precious Очень ценное — драгоценный

Very weak — feeble Очень слабый —

Very wicked — villainous Очень злой — злодейский

Very wise — sagacious Очень мудрый — прозорливый

Very worried — anxious Очень беспокоит — тревожный

Very young — Очень молод — Зелень

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you need a synonym of _очень_?

Comment: @YellowSky Thank you for asking! I elaborated a bit on my question and hope that it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Very much - I don't think you could translate it that way. For instance, "Thank you very much" would be translated as "Спасибо большое".

Answer (score 5):

**Очень много**

1) Как у дурака фантиков.

- Да у него денег, *как у дурака фантиков*.

2) Клондайк!

- Сколько у тебя инструментов! Целый *клондайк*!

**Очень громко**

Как раненный зверь.

- Чего орешь, *как раненный зверь*?

**Очень шумно**

Как медведь.

- Ходил по комнате *как медведь*.

**Очень мало**

Как украл.

- Принес воды *как украл*.

**Очень мал** (рост)

Метр с кепкой.

- Да у него рост - *метр с кепкой*.

**Очень жарко**

Пекло!

- В комнате было *пекло*.

**Cлишком долго**

Только за смертью посылать.

- Где ты ходил? Тебя *только за смертью посылать*.

**Cлишком высок** (рост)

1) дядя Степа.

2) Каланча.

**Очень короткий**

Огрызок.

- От провода остался *огрызок*.

**Очень быстро**

Как пуля.

- Пассажир пробежал *как пуля*.

**Очень медленно**

Как черепаха.

- Школьник плелся *как черепаха*.
- Поезд ехал *как черепаха*.

**Очень часто**

Как из пулемета.

- *Как из пулемета* вылетали листы печатающей машинки.

**Очень далеко**

За горизонтом.

- Муж *за горизонтом*.

**Очень близко**

Под носом.

- Книга у тебя *под носом*.

**Очень толстый**

Жиртрест.

- Ну ты и *жиртрест*...

**Очень стар**

Да из него уже песок сыпется.

**Очень молод**

1) Зелень.

- *Зелень* ещё, чтобы сделать это.

2) Два вершка от горшка.

- *Два вершка от горшка*, а даешь советы!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget, "very" before adjectives and adverbs can often be translated with the augmentative prefix `пре-` attached to those adjectives and adverbs, so "very much" can well be translated as "премного", "very big" as "пребольшой", etc.
Still, not every adjectives or adverb has this form with `пре-`, e.g. "медленно/медленный" hasn't got it.

Answer (score 2):

**Очень громко** -- как потерпевший -- Что вы кричите как потерпевший?

**Очень глупо** -- тупой, тупой как пробка -- Он тупой, как пробка (про человека или животное). 
*НО:* Тупые мысли, тупые поступки (здесь "как пробка" ставить не надо).

**Очень зол** -- как собака -- Она злая, как собака.

Comment: Thank you for you contribution. Please feel free to correct my mistakes or even the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments to words that you wrote (my comments only about Russian words and phrases and their correspondence to each other, not about accuracy of translation).

1. *Very beautiful — exquisite Очень красивый — изысканная*

I would prefer here `очаровательный` instead of `изысканный`.

2. *Very bright — dazzling Очень яркий — ослепляет*

`ослепляет` is verb in present tense, you can use `ослепляющий` (participle). Be careful with `ослепительный` - it often means `очень красивый`.

3. *Very dirty — squalid Очень грязный — убогий*

`убогий` is incorrect. You can use `грязный как свинья`.

4. *Very hungry — ravenous Очень голоден — хищный*

`хищный` is incorrect. You can use `голодный как волк`.

5. *Very poor — destitute Очень плохое — нищие*

Incorrect. `Нищий` (it can be noun and adjective) means `[person] without money`.

6. *Very roomy — spacious Очень вместительный — просторный*

Not good. `вместительный` is applicable mainly to transport (cars, trucks, buses, planes) and containers (bags, backpacks, etc.), `просторный` - to rooms and buildings (But both of them could be used for cars).

7. *Very strong — unyielding Очень сильный — неуступчивый*

Incorrect. `Непобедимый` will be better.

8. *Very thin — gaunt Очень тонкая — тощий*

Incorrect. `Тощий` means `очень худой`, for `очень тонкий` you can use `тонюсенький`.

9. *Very capable — accomplished Очень способный — осуществляется

   Very cold — freezing Очень холодно — замораживание

   Very eager — keen Очень хотелось — сильно

   Very neat — immaculate Очень аккуратно — совершенные

   Very tired — exhausted Очень устал — исчерпаны*

This is meaningless and looks like bad machine translation. I can recommend:

- `Очень способный` - `схватывает на лету` (about learning)
- `Очень холодно` - `морозно` (adverb), also `дубак`, `холодрыга` (both are slang nouns, both are used to describe weather).
- `Очень хотелось` - `невтерпеж` (adverb)
- `Очень устал` - `вымотанный` (participle)

Also many of words in your pairs are different parts of speech or have different gender. For example: `Очень глупо — идиотизм`. `глупо` is adverb, `идиотизм` is noun.

Comment: Thank you very much, and for pointing out my mistakes. I still have a lot to learn. Please feel free to correct my mistakes or even the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Слишком мало (обычно о ресурсах) - кот наплакал.

Очень много (чего-то полезного или хорошего) - навалом. (У Маши денег кот наплакал, зато у Билла Гейтса их навалом.)

Очень много денег - денег куры не клюют.

Очень глупое замечание - не смеши мои тапочки, бред, бредятина, бред сивой кобылы, чушь собачья.

Очень худой:
1. Тоненькая, тонкая (seldom about males) - positive
2. Тощий - negative, but not offensive
3. Худющий - negative, but again not offensive, it is often told about children and animals
4. Дистрофик - may be either offensive or a medical diagnosis

Очень толстый: жирный, жирдяй, жиртрест (all of these are offensive)

Очень любить: обожать

Очень обидеться: смертельно обидеться

Очень хороший/красивый: потрясающий